# Bootstrap - making one text box longer than others

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have three text boxes on my page. I want to make one text box bigger than others. I tried writing the below code:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <mat-form-field (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
              <input matInput placeholder="Last Name"  >
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-error >Required</mat-error>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
          <mat-form-field (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
              <input matInput placeholder="First Name" >
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-error >Required</mat-error>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">

        <mat-form-field (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
            <input matInput placeholder="E-mail"  >
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-error >Required</mat-error>
    </div>


  </div>
```

I want the email text box to become bigger/lengthier. I tried putting col-md-8. If I do that then the text box moves to the next row. I want all three text boxes on the same row.

Below is the image of the page:

[image]

when I changed the first text box to col-md-2 and sewcond to col-md-2 and third one to col-md-8 then the text box moves to another row. Below is the image:
[image]

Comment: At top col total must be 12 so make 2 - 2 - 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total col count up to 12 so if u want to make 8 last one then make others 2

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <mat-form-field (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
              <input matInput placeholder="Last Name"  >
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-error >Required</mat-error>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <mat-form-field (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
              <input matInput placeholder="First Name" >
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-error >Required</mat-error>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">

        <mat-form-field (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
            <input matInput placeholder="E-mail"  >
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-error >Required</mat-error>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: I did exactly like you told me and email text box moved to another row. I pasted the image above in my original post.

Comment: then u should set also col-sm-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-8. For small device sizes bootsrap auto change its size